# How to get xml node value by attribute value with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got some xml generated by a external service looking like this:

```
<data>
    <eventlist>
        <events>
            <event id="123">
                <eventdescription lang="de">description_de</eventdescription>
                <eventdescription lang="en">descrition_en</eventdescription>
            </event>
            <event id="456">
                <eventdescription lang="de">description_de</eventdescription>
                <eventdescription lang="en">descrition_en</eventdescription>
            </event>
        </events>
    </eventlist>
</data>
```

I'm loading this xml with simplexml and loop over the events:

```
$responseXml = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl);
$lang = 'de';
foreach($responseXml->eventlist->events->children() as $event){
    // get eventdescription
}
```

Now I want to get the string/text ofthe eventdescription for every event in the right language based on the `$lang` variable. So if it's set to `de` I want all descriptions with the attribute `lang="de"`.

I've tried

```
echo( $event->eventdescription[0]);
```

which kinda works (assuming `de` and `en` are always in the same order), but using var_dump reveals, that it's not just the string only

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'lang' => string 'de' (length=2)
      public 0 => string 'description_de' (length=14)
```

So how do I get only the string of the `eventdescription` node? Is there a better way to make the language selection should the languages not always be in the same order?

Comment: Well first of all, you could simply loop over all eventdescription nodes, and then inside that loop check what lang attribute value they have set ... and then only _do_ something further with those nodes, if it is the one you are looking for. So far, so trivial ... Of course you could also f.e. go the XPath way, and directly select only the elements with the correct language to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Answered elsewhere, but use XPATH:

```
 $events = $responseXml->xpath('//data[eventlist[events[event[eventdescription[@lang="de"]]]]]');
```

Comment: TBH with XML I resort to string parsing 50% of the time because 1. You can't trust anyone these days 2. Whist IT coworkers will vilify you for horrible code business owners will pay you for working code

Answer (score 0):

Or using your loop:

```
$lang = 'de';

foreach($responseXml->eventlist->events->children() as $event){
    $description = (string) current($event->xpath('eventdescription[@lang="'.$lang.'"]'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Again using XPath, but just an example of how you could use it to build a list of strings for a particular translation...

```
$requestUrl = <<<XML
<data>
    <eventlist>
        <events>
            <event id="123">
                <eventdescription lang="de">description_de123</eventdescription>
                <eventdescription lang="en">descrition_en123</eventdescription>
            </event>
            <event id="456">
                <eventdescription lang="de">description_de456</eventdescription>
                <eventdescription lang="en">descrition_en456</eventdescription>
            </event>
        </events>
    </eventlist>
</data>
XML;
$responseXml = simplexml_load_string($requestUrl);
$lang = 'de';
$trans = [];
foreach($responseXml->xpath("//event[eventdescription[@lang='$lang']]") as $event){
    $trans[(int)$event["id"]] = (string)$event->eventdescription;
}
print_r($trans);
```

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [123] => description_de123
    [456] => description_de456
)
```